# How do i set ComboBoxItem as selected from the button inside it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, command

**Goal**: To set item as selected on button click (Button is inside the ComboBoxItem) which is Binded to DeleteItemCommand.

**Progress**: I am getting the command fired successfully. And by selecting the item first later clicking the button successfully deletes the comboboxitem.

**Xaml**:

```
     <ComboBox 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Width="149" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding LoadCustomValue}" 
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomValueName}"/>
                            <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=root, 
                                             Path=DataContext.Command}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Content="Delete" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ComboBox>
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**:

```cs
class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<SavedCustomValue> _loadCustomValue;
        private SavedCustomValue _selectedValue;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public SavedCustomValue SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _selectedValue; }
            set { _selectedValue = value; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<SavedCustomValue> LoadCustomValue
        {
            get { return _loadCustomValue; }
            set { _loadCustomValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            _loadCustomValue = new ObservableCollection<SavedCustomValue>()
            {
                new SavedCustomValue(){ CustomValueName="Custom Value 1"   },
                new SavedCustomValue(){ CustomValueName="Custom Value 2"   },
                new SavedCustomValue(){ CustomValueName="Custom Value 3"   }
            }; 
        }
        p private ICommand _command;

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(
                   x =>
                   {
                       Execute();
                   }));
            }

        }
        private void Execute()
        {
            LoadCustomScan.Remove(SelectedScan);
            MessageBox.Show(LoadCustomScan.Count.ToString());
        }
        public class SavedCustomValue
        {
            public string CustomValueName { get; set; }          
        }
    }
```

I am totally new in Wpf so consider explaining me please.

Comment: Use `RelayCommand` class - [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic). Then pass `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` to the Command. And you will not need binding of `SelectedItem` then.

Comment: The mistake: change `SelectedValue=` to `SelectedItem=`. Tip: `Mode=TwoWay` is default here, you may not set it explicitly.

Comment: will try now and revert back. Thanks

Comment: i made the changes as you suggested but i am still not able to delete the item.Button click is working fine as before. Do you want me to add the update the code viewmodel code?

Comment: Sure, update the code of both

Comment: One more tip: PropertyChanged call must be with Property name, not name of the backing field: `OnPropertyChanged("LoadCustomValue")`. As you have `[CallerMemberName]` in INPC implementation, you may call it without arguments: `OnPropertyChanged()`, compiler will fill it for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks. i didn't know about [CallerMemberName] has that benefit.
Can you tell me what am i missing or something in the code above since i am not able to delete the item yet. Thanks for your time. I appreciate alot.

Comment: One more tip `public class SavedCustomValue` - don't use nested type, move the class to namespace, outside of View Model class.

Comment: Yet another tip: `_loadCustomValue = new ...` never interact with backing field outside of property getter/setter, it can make INPC implementation useless, interact with property instead: `LoadCustomValue = new ...`.

Comment: Noted! Thanks alot. @aepot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass the parameter, you aren't using it. Use it:

```csharp
private ICommand _myCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is SavedCustomValue v)
    {
        LoadCustomValue.Remove(v);
        MessageBox.Show(LoadCustomValue.Count.ToString());
    }
}));
```

Also don't name the command as `Command` to avoid conflict with standard Command class. I renamed it to `MyCommand`.